# Push to Array does not actually push

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, mapping

Community,

I've been banging my head over the following problem and hope you can spot my mistake. I deploy the following contract with `Populus` on `Testrpc`. This is pretty simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ICO {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    address[] public buyers;

    uint constant public MULTIPLIER = 1000;

    function ICO() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getBuyersLength() public constant returns (uint) {
        return buyers.length;
    }

    function buy() public payable {
        uint coins = msg.value * MULTIPLIER;
        balances[msg.sender] += coins;
        buyers.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

I am calling the `buy` function with Web3js in the following way:

```
let contract;
let account;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Using MetaMask connection');
        w3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        w3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }

    contract = w3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress);
    account = w3.eth.defaultAccount;

    main()

});

function main() {
    let amount = w3.toWei(10, 'ether');
    contract.buy({'value': amount}, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Transaction created: ' + res);
        }
    })
}
```

After waiting for the transaction to be included in a block (happens almost instantaneously since I run `testrpc`, I call the `getBuyersLength()` function like this:

```
function updateBalances() {
    contract.getBuyersLength(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error in getBuyers: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Count of Buyers: ' + res);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the results is always `0`, which means that the `buyers.length` stays the same. Can you spot a mistake I've made?

Comment: Let me know your feedback on my ans. If its resolved please mark as solved. It would be helpful for community to find ans easily

Comment: With testrpc/ganache-cli you can use https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/ that provides an interface to browse blocks/transactions. If the array didn't increase its length then `buy()` has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it. The problem was how I deployed the contract to `TestRPC`. I used `populus deploy ICO -c testrpc` to deploy the contract, but somehow, the contract was never saved on the test blockchain. I now deploy the contract from the frontend, which is not the best solution, but it works for now. Here's how:

```
w3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
account = w3.eth.defaultAccount;

let contractScheme = w3.eth.contract(contractABI);
let gasEstimate = w3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractBytecode});
contract = contractScheme.new({
    data: contractBytecode,
    from: account,
    gas: gasEstimate
}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error occurred in Contract Creation: ' + err)
    } else {
        // Callback fires twice. Once upon reception of the TransactionHash and
        // once the contract receives an address.
        if (!res.address) {
            console.log('TransactionID for Contract Creation ' + res.transactionHash)
        } 
        if (res.address) {
            console.log('Contract Address: ' + res.address);
            main()
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your contract seems to be ok. Might be issue in your Js main file `w3.toWei` function. I guess you didn't assign any web3 object to w3. So w3 is undefined, Javascript will throw error. Because no deification found for `w3.toWei`. So your statements will not execute, `contract.buy()` will not execute. If this method is not executed then there is no trans in Eth client. So when you call `getBuyersLength()` it will return 0 only.

```
function main() {
    let contract = web3.eth.contract(CONTRACT_ABI).at(CONTRACT_ADDR);
    let amount = web3.toWei(10, 'ether');
    contract.buy({'value': amount}, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('Transaction created: ' + res);
        }
    })
}
```

Replace your code with above mentioned code. If your problem not resolved then update your qus with Javascript logs.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve my issue. I assign w3 to web3 earlier in my script. I'll added it to the question. But thank you!